# it is necessarty to fill this gap ? on eyeball?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I am making a lowpoly character , and like to animate in couples of days, but I would like to know if I need to fill this limit ? this rings of the edge loops around the eye? consider this is the first loops of the eye or the final, depends how you can see it, I ve started to model over this area with few verts on it, however I am on the eye right now, see the picture, must leave it away? or fill the interior ?

[image]

see the whole picture.

Comment: Are you okay with the character not having eyelids? If the character will never need to blink, I suppose what you have is alright, but I would model eyelids. As far as texturing the inside of the eyelids, anywhere that won't be visible (even when animated) doesn't need to be textured.

Comment: Please edit this question to be more clear. Proper grammar and punctuation are an important part of helping us help you.

Comment: I need him to blink , I won´t use cycles for the moment, I mean , I do not want to create corneas with glossy or shine iris extra geometrys, just the eyeball and the  pupil, the basic for blink.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working low poly it would better to close it and colour it black. It would be different if you were going for max realism but at the moment I don't think it's necersarry. You may also find it easier yo UV unrap.

Comment: I´d like this character to blink , so I am going to model the eyelid, so should I make a kind of capsule inside? or should I close matching edges? by the way I need this character able to blink , for the moments I won´t use cycles for "trasparent corneas" or Iris reflection, I just want to blink for animation and try to use not much polys -

Comment: I'm not sure if modelling the eye lid separately is necessary. Try adding shape keys to the head mesh or add a rig for it. Animating the face will be easier that way.